# Django JsonResponse lose precision when received by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a big int such as `6222600820001059483` in python int type. When I send to browser use `JsonResponse` I found that the value was changed to `6222600820001060000`.

I think this caused by the precison lose when JsonResponse send it to browser.

I think this was caused by javascript. Like [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) said the javascript's highest integer is small than this value.

So how to deal this between django and js?

Comment: Do you calculate anything with this value? You could keep it as string.

Comment: Yeah,May be this is the right way.I read this data from pandas.So I must convert the big int field in pandas to str.